# Java jfreechart stick scatterplot?

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am using jfreechart at the moment and want to generate a kind of scatterplot. I have 100000s of datapoints. Now I want to change each 2D point into a (3D-) stick by usind the points z-value as the stick height. The whole plot should be zoomable!
Thats it. Is this possible in jfreechart?
How can I do this without bucking or delay within the zooming action?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Achim

Answer (score 2):

For ~10<sup>6</sup> data points, [`FastScatterPlot`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/FastScatterPlot.html) is a good choice. For larger numbers, you'll have to test.

Addendum: The good news is that zooming works very well, and you can set the initial zoom area as needed.

Addendum: For speed, `FastScatterPlot` uses an internal [`render()`](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jfree/chart/plot/FastScatterPlot.java#L572) method, instead of a plug-in renderer. Rather than rendering a shape, consider using a spectrum of colors that vary in saturation or transparency.