# Plotting a locus in XY space using JFreeChart

Tags: jfreechart

I would like to plot the locus of a particle in two dimensional space.

My data is a sequence of X,Y coordinates and I would like to plot these.

Would appreciate any pointers to examples that show how to do this.

An example of a locus plot can be seen below:
[image]

Note: I'd like to show the path as a continuous line with arrows showing the direction of motion.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ChartFactory.createScatterPlot()`, illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:230513%20%5Bjfreechart%5D%20ChartFactory.createScatterPlot), might be a good starting point.

[image]

`FastScatterPlot`, cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8533194/230513) and illustrated [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartFastScatterPlotDemo.htm), may be required for larger datasets.

Addendum: Looking at your revised question, I've not seen a renderer like that. You might look at a [`org.jfree.chart.annotations`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/annotations/package-summary.html) such as `XYShapeAnnotation` using a `GeneralPath`. These [`ArcTest`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:230513%20%5Bjfreechart%5D%20ArcTest) variations may offer guidance. See also [`PointyThing`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15607737/230513).

[image]

Comment: basically need continuous line to show the motion path and arrows on the line to show the direction of motion

Comment: I flipped through the examples - I think all I need is somehow to affix arrows to show the path of motion. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe a filled `Polygon`? A `PIE` closed sector of an `Arc2d`? Rotation?

Comment: mmmm no I just want to show the path of travel so the lineto stuff is good but I'd just like arrows every so often on the line to show the direction