FastScatterPlot not displaying data
I am trying to build a charting application as a project for college, using JFreeChart to build the graphs and Swing to build the UI. After some debugging Im at a point where the file parser is reading the data correctly, the chart is being built and the panel containing the chart is being displayed to the user. But the chart does not contain the data. Here is the code that builds my scatter plot:
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartUtils;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.FastScatterPlot;


public class ScatterPlot extends Chart{

    

    public ScatterPlot(String title, float[][] data) {
            
        this.data = data;
        //CSVParser.printArrayToConsole(this.data[1]);
        NumberAxis domainAxis = new NumberAxis("X");
        domainAxis.setAutoRangeIncludesZero(false);
        NumberAxis rangeAxis = new NumberAxis("Y");
        rangeAxis.setAutoRangeIncludesZero(true);
        FastScatterPlot plot = new FastScatterPlot(this.data, domainAxis, rangeAxis);
        JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart("Fast Scatter Plot", plot);
        ChartUtils.applyCurrentTheme(chart);

        panel = new ChartPanel(chart);
        panel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(500, 270));
        panel.setMinimumDrawHeight(10);
        panel.setMaximumDrawHeight(2000);
        panel.setMinimumDrawWidth(20);
        panel.setMaximumDrawWidth(2000);

    }
}

Here is the Chart class from which that inherits:
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.FastScatterPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;


public class Chart {
    
    float[][] data;
    ChartPanel panel;
    
    public Chart(){
        initChartPanel();
    }
    
    private void initChartPanel(){
        float[][] tempData = {{0}, {0}};
        FastScatterPlot plot = new FastScatterPlot(tempData, new NumberAxis(""), new NumberAxis(""));
        JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart("If you're seeing this, something went wrong.", plot);
        panel = new ChartPanel(chart);
    }
    
}

Here is the dataset i used for this output (read from a CSV file):
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11
4.2,4,3.7,3.4,3.2,2.9,2.6,2.4,2.1,1.8,1.5,1.2

Here is the output of running this code:
Scatter plot with no data
I have tried:

setting the range manually
disabling setAutoRange
adding the ability to zoom to see if the points were too small to be seen (nope)
resizing the points using an extension of the FastScatterPlot class that someone else wrote

As a sidenote, the ScatterPlot class was written by a teammate of mine and im quite certain that he did not write it himself but instead just copy and pasted it from a tutorial. We agreed that Id build the UI and hed handle the chart-building side of things. I made a few modifications to fit into what I have, but this is to say Im not really familiar with JFreeChart and I believe neither is he so I cant ask him for help.
Any help is appreciated.

Edit: the ChartPanel is added to my MainFrame in that class, here are all the classes needed to be able to run the path that gets you that output.
package javacharts;
import java.awt.*;

public class JavaCharts {
    
    static GraphicsDevice device = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        MainFrame mainFrame = new MainFrame();
        device.setFullScreenWindow(mainFrame);
    }
    
}

package javacharts;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.*;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame{
    JPanel mainPanel;
    JLabel title, choiceLabel;
    JButton[] buttons;
    JLabel[] buttonLabels;
    GridBagConstraints constraints;
    //These values need ot be atomic or []
    //because the compiler complains about it being referenced from a lambda as an int
    AtomicInteger graphType; 
    AtomicInteger inputType;
    
    public MainFrame(){
        graphType = new AtomicInteger();
        inputType = new AtomicInteger();
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        
        //declare big labels
        title = new JLabel("Welcome to Java Charts", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        title.setFont(title.getFont().deriveFont(48.0f));
        
        choiceLabel = new JLabel("", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        choiceLabel.setFont(choiceLabel.getFont().deriveFont(30.0f));
        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 0;
        constraints.gridwidth = 3;
        mainPanel.add(choiceLabel, constraints);
        
        //declare buttons, used for both graph type and input type
        buttons = new JButton[3];
        buttons[0] = new JButton();
        buttons[1] = new JButton();
        buttons[2] = new JButton();
        
        //declare button labels
        buttonLabels = new JLabel[3];
        buttonLabels[0] = new JLabel("Scatter Plot", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        buttonLabels[0].setFont(buttonLabels[0].getFont().deriveFont(18.0f));
        buttonLabels[1] = new JLabel("Box Plot", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        buttonLabels[1].setFont(buttonLabels[1].getFont().deriveFont(18.0f));
        buttonLabels[2] = new JLabel("Ogive", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        buttonLabels[2].setFont(buttonLabels[2].getFont().deriveFont(18.0f));
        
        
        //add buttons to mainPanel
        constraints.gridy = 1;
        constraints.gridwidth = 1;
        constraints.insets = new Insets(15, 10, 0, 10);
        mainPanel.add(buttons[0], constraints);
        
        constraints.gridx = 1;
        mainPanel.add(buttons[1], constraints);
        
        constraints.gridx = 2;
        mainPanel.add(buttons[2], constraints);
        
        //add button labels to main panel
        constraints.gridy = 2;
        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.insets.top = 0;
        mainPanel.add(buttonLabels[0], constraints);
        
        constraints.gridx = 1;
        mainPanel.add(buttonLabels[1], constraints);
        
        constraints.gridx = 2;
        mainPanel.add(buttonLabels[2], constraints);
        
        this.add(title, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        this.add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setUndecorated(true);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
        buildChartSelectionMenu();
    }
    
    public void buildChartSelectionMenu(){
        choiceLabel.setText("Which type of graph would you like to build?");
        
        //change icons of buttons
        //IMPORTANT: change images to the actual outputted graphs at the end
        ImageIcon icon1 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("..\\images\\scatter_plot.jpeg"));
        buttons[0].setIcon(icon1);
        ImageIcon icon2 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("..\\images\\box_plot.jpeg"));
        buttons[1].setIcon(icon2);
        ImageIcon icon3 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("..\\images\\ogive.jpeg"));
        buttons[2].setIcon(icon3);
        
        //add action listeners to buttons
        for(AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger(0); i.get() < buttons.length; i.incrementAndGet()){
            int chartT = i.get();
            buttons[i.get()].addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
                graphType.set(chartT);
                buildInputSelectionMenu();
            });
        }
        
        //change button labels
        buttonLabels[0].setText("Scatter Plot");
        buttonLabels[1].setText("Box Plot");
        buttonLabels[2].setText("Ogive");
    }
    
    public void buildInputSelectionMenu(){
        //remove all action listeners from buttons
        for(int i = 0; i < buttons.length; ++i){
            buttons[i].removeActionListener(buttons[i].getActionListeners()[0]);
        }
        
        //change icons of buttons
        ImageIcon icon1 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("../images/excel.jpeg"));
        buttons[0].setIcon(icon1);
        ImageIcon icon2 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("../images/csv.jpeg"));
        buttons[1].setIcon(icon2);
        ImageIcon icon3 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("../images/mouse_cursor.jpeg"));
        buttons[2].setIcon(icon3);
        
        //change labels
        choiceLabel.setText("How would you like to build this graph?");
        buttonLabels[0].setText("Excel file");
        buttonLabels[1].setText("CSV file");
        buttonLabels[2].setText("Input data manually");
        
        //add new action listeners to buttons
        for(AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger(0); i.get() < buttons.length; i.incrementAndGet()){
            int inputT = i.get();
            buttons[i.get()].addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
                inputType.set(inputT);
                try{
                    ChartBuilder chartBuilder = new ChartBuilder(graphType.get(), inputType.get());
                    //System.out.println("Hello from mainfram");
                    getContentPane().removeAll();
                    super.add(chartBuilder.chart.panel);
                } catch(Exception ex){
                    buildChartSelectionMenu();
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}

package javacharts;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ChartBuilder {
    int chartType;
    int inputType;
    File fileIn;
    InputHandler inputHandler;
    Chart chart;
    //JFreeChart chart;
    
    public ChartBuilder(int chartType, int inputType)throws FileNotFoundException{
        //System.out.println(inputType);
        
        float[][] data = new float[2][];
        
        switch(inputType){
            case 0:
                break;
            case 1:
                inputHandler = new CSVParser();
                if(inputHandler.file == null){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File is null",
                    "Error in ChartBuilder", 
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    break;
                }
                
                data = inputHandler.parseData();
                if(data == null){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "CSVParser.parseData() failed to return valid array",
                    "Error in CSVParser", 
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    break;
                }
                if(data[0] == null){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "CSVParser.convertToFloarArray() failed to return valid array",
                    "Error in CSVParser", 
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                break;
        }
        
        switch(chartType){
            case 0:
                chart = new ScatterPlot("title", data);
                break;
            case 1:
                break;
            case 2:
                break;
        }
    }
}

package javacharts;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class CSVParser extends InputHandler{
    
    final public String EXTENSION = ".csv";
    
    public CSVParser() throws FileNotFoundException{
        try{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Make sure your CSV file contains only numerical data (no titles/labels)",
                "Attention", 
                JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            file = openFile();
        } catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Failed to open file",
                "Error in CSVParser", 
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            file = null;
        }
        
        boolean validFile = false;
        try{
            validFile = isValidFile(EXTENSION);
        } catch(Exception e){
            validFile = false;
        }
        
        if(!validFile){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please select a CSV file",
                "Invalid file type", 
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            file = null;
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public float[][] parseData() throws FileNotFoundException{
        float[][] data = new float[2][];
        BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        try{
            final String DELIMITER = ",";
            
            String line;
            int i = 0;
            while((line = fileReader.readLine()) != null){
                String[] lineData = line.split(DELIMITER);
                //printArrayToConsole(lineData);
                data[i] = convertToFloatArray(lineData);
                //printArrayToConsole(data[i]);
                ++i;
            }
        } catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Failed to read file",
                    "Error in CSVParser", 
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            System.out.println(e);
            return null;
        }
        
        return data;
    }
    
    public float[] convertToFloatArray(String[] arrIn){
        float[] arrOut = new float[arrIn.length];
        
        try{
            for(int i = 0; i < arrIn.length; ++i){
                arrOut[i] = Float.parseFloat(arrIn[i]);
            }
        } catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Failed to convert all values to floats",
                    "Error in CSVParser", 
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            System.out.println(e);
            return null;
        }
        return arrOut;
    }
    
    public void printArrayToConsole(String[] arr){
        System.out.println("String array");
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i){
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    
    public static void printArrayToConsole(float[] arr){
        System.out.println("Float Array");
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i){
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}

package javacharts;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public abstract class InputHandler {
    float[][] data = new float[2][];
    File file;
    String filePath;
    
    
    public File openFile(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        int retVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(frame);
        if(retVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            this.filePath = chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
            return chooser.getSelectedFile();
        } else{
            return null;
        }
    }
    
    public boolean isValidFile(String extension){
        return filePath.endsWith(extension) ? true : false;
    }
    
    abstract public float[][] parseData() throws FileNotFoundException;
}

Obviously I still have some work to do as I havent built my other 2 InputHandlers or implemented the other 2 chart types, but what Ive been doing so far is only going through the path that is supposed to create a scatter plot from a CSV file.
I hope its not too much code but thats whats needed in order to reproduce my output.

Edit 2: I got it working by changing the entire ScatterPlot class to use an XYDataset and the ChartFactory.createScatterPlot() method instead of using FastScatterPlot. This is what that class looks like now:
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;  
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;  
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;  



public class ScatterPlot extends Chart{

    

    public ScatterPlot(String[] labels, float[][] data) {
            
            super(labels, data);
            XYDataset dataset = createDataset();

            JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createScatterPlot(
                    labels[0], labels[1], labels[2],
                    dataset
            );

            setChartPanel(chart);
    }
        
        private XYDataset createDataset() {  
            XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();  
            
            XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Series 1");
            
            for(int i = 0; i < data[0].length; ++i){
                series.add(data[0][i], data[1][i]);
            }
            
            dataset.addSeries(series);
            return dataset;
        }
}



I don't see where you add your new ChartPanel to the enclosing frame; please [edit] your question to include a [mre] that shows your revised approach.

Edited my post to add the rest of the code needed to run the program

Construct and manipulate Swing GUI objects only on the event dispatch thread. Why AtomicInteger? Don't delete the enclosing ChartPanel; update it's chart or dataset as needed, for example .  A minimal example will allow you to focus on the chart display; debugging may reveal how far the data gets.

I will have to read up on the event dispatch thread, and probably much more. This is my first time building a proper app with Swing so I dont really know what im doing.
AtomicInteger because that variable is being referenced from inside the lambda of the ActionListener, and the compiler complains that it must be final or effectively final. int[] would also work.
I dont see where im deleting my ChartPanel, is that in the MainFrame class?

If you start on the event dispatch thread, the listener should run on  the event dispatch thread. It should be OK to replace the chart in the ChartPanel via setChart().

Focusing on displaying the chart and updating it dynamically, the example below alters the chart in situ using the setData() method provided by FastScatterPlot. Pressing the Update button invokes setData(), and the listening chart updates itself in response. Your actionPerformed() implementation can solicit a file, parse its data, and update the plot as needed; more here.


import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.FastScatterPlot;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/78322223/230513
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/8533194/230513
 */
public class FastScatterPlotDemo {

    private static final int N = 10 * 1_000;
    private static final Random rnd = new Random();

    private void display() {
        var f = new JFrame("Fast Scatter Plot");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        var domainAxis = new NumberAxis("X");
        domainAxis.setAutoRangeIncludesZero(false);
        NumberAxis rangeAxis = new NumberAxis("Y");
        var plot = new FastScatterPlot(createData(), domainAxis, rangeAxis);
        var chart = new JFreeChart(f.getTitle(), plot);
        var panel = new ChartPanel(chart, true) {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(16 * 32, 10 * 32);
            }
        };
        f.add(panel);
        var buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Update") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                plot.setData(createData());
            }
        }));
        f.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private float[][] createData() {
        float[][] data = new float[2][N];
        for (int i = 0; i < data[0].length; i++) {
            data[0][i] = (float) i;
            data[1][i] = (float) rnd.nextGaussian() * N;
        }
        return data;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new FastScatterPlotDemo()::display);

    }
}

